# I am using Django 2.2 and I am try to use django-star-ratings 0.7.0

Tags: python, django

I have installed django-star-ratings 0.7.0 on my virtualenv and also added 'star-ratings' in my `INSTALLED_APPS` at setting.py but I still got this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'star_ratings'

```
(paktour) PS D:\Django2\dev\paktour\src\myApp> pip list
Package                  Version
------------------------ -----------
Babel                    2.6.0
closure                  20180204
Django                   2.2
django-braces            1.13.0
django-crispy-forms      1.7.2
django-formset-js        0.5.0
django-generic-ratings   0.7
django-jquery            3.1.0
django-jquery-js         3.1.1
django-model-utils       3.1.2
django-multi-form-view   2.0.1
django-multiselectfield  0.1.8
django-phonenumber-field 2.2.0
django-star-ratings      0.7.0
django-tags-input        4.4.2
mysql-connector-python   8.0.15
mysqlclient              1.4.2.post1
phonenumbers             8.10.8
Pillow                   5.4.1
pip                      19.0.3
protobuf                 3.7.1
PyMySQL                  0.9.3
pytz                     2018.9
setuptools               40.8.0
six                      1.12.0
sqlparse                 0.3.0
swapper                  1.1.0
wheel                    0.33.1
```

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'star_ratings',
    'paktour',
]
```

Comment: Welcome! What is your question?

Answer (score 3):

Python module names may not contain dashes – in general, they're replaced with underscores.

If you look at the [installation instructions](https://django-star-ratings.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation), they say to add `star_ratings`, not `star-ratings`.

Comment: Still got this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'star_ratings'

Comment: Please update your question with the exact relevant code you have and the error message with the traceback intact.

Comment: Update the question.

Comment: I added INSTALLED_APPS pip list and I got erorr ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'star_ratings' when run the command on window shell: python manage.py runserver

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're in the same virtualenv?

Comment: Yes, I was in the right env and this command work for me: pip install django-star-ratings -I -U by the way thanks a lot for your time